# Applying Neural Network to forecast prices

Tags: matlab, neural-network, svm

I have read this line about neural networks :

> "Although the perceptron rule finds a successful weight vector when
>   the training examples are linearly separable, it can fail to converge
>   if the examples are not linearly separable.

My data distribution is like this :The features are production of rubber ,consumption of rubber , production of synthetic rubber and exchange rate all values are scaled

[image]

My question is that the data is not linearly separable so should i apply ANN  on it or not? is this a rule that it should be applied on linerly separable data only ? as i am getting good results using it (0.09% MAPE error) . I have also applied SVM regression (**fitrsvm** function in **MATLAB**)so I have to ask can SVM be used in forecasting /prediction or it is used only for classification I haven't read anywhere about using SVM to forecast , and the results for SVM are also not good what can be the possible reason?

Comment: This might be true for a single neuron. But given enough neurons a neural net can approximate any function. [Here](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap4.html) is a nice, visual proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neural networks are not perceptrons. Perceptron is on of the oldest ideas, which is at most a single building block of neural networks. Perceptron is designed for binary, linear classification and your problem is neither the binary classification nor linearly separable. You are looking at regression here, where neural networks are a good fit.

> can SVM be used in forecasting /prediction or it is used only for classification I haven't read anywhere about using SVM to forecast , and the results for SVM are also not good what can be the possible reason?

SVM has regression "clone" called SVR which can be used for any task NN (as a regressor) can be used. There are of course some typical characteristics of both (like SVR being non parametric estimator etc.). For the task at hand - both approaches (as well as any another regressor, there are dozens of them!) is fine.

Comment: Can you explain about svm in regression